# Differences between vanilla three js vs react-three-fiber code, not able to figure out what is different

Tags: reactjs, canvas, three.js, requestanimationframe, react-three-fiber

Following code works just fine and renders the geometry with all the attributes set i.e. color, uvs, normal and vertices.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
const { useEffect } = require("react");

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 150;
  const aspect = 2;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 5;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const color = 0xFFFFFF;
  const intensity = 1;
  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
  light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
  scene.add(light);

  const positions = [...somepoints];
  const normals = [...somepoints];
  const uvs = [...somepoints];
  const colours = [...somepoints];

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const positionNumComponents = 3;
  const normalNumComponents = 3;
  const uvNumComponents = 2;
  const colorComp = 4;
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'position',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), positionNumComponents));
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'normal',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(normals), normalNumComponents));
  geometry.setAttribute(
      'uv',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(uvs), uvNumComponents));
        geometry.setAttribute(
      'color',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colours), colorComp));


  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x88FF88});

  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  function render(time) {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    main();
  });

  return (
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  )
}

export default App;
```

However if I try to run it using react components it doesn't show anything and I get the following error  `235 [.WebGL-0x38089eaa00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call`:

I think that the problem might be with requestAnimationFrame but in above code it doesn't even perform any computation on the scene's object. It just calls renderer.render which react three fiber takes care off, right?

```
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import * as THREE from "three";

const App = () => {

  const positions = [...somepoints];
  const normals = [...somepoints];
  const uvs = [...somepoints];
  const colours = [...somepoints];

    return (
        <Canvas>
          <perspectiveCamera
            fov={150}
            aspect={2}
            position={[0,0,5]}
            near={0.1}
            far={100}
            />
            <directionalLight
              color={0xFFFFFF}
              intensity={1.5}
              position={[-1, 2, 4]}
            />
            <mesh>
              <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
                <bufferAttribute
                  attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
                  count={positions.length / 3}
                  itemSize={3}
                  array={positions}
                  normalized={true}
                />
                <bufferAttribute
                  attachObject={["attributes", "normal"]}
                  count={normals.length / 3}
                  itemSize={3}
                  array={normals}
                  normalized={true}
                />
                <bufferAttribute
                  attachObject={["attributes", "color"]}
                  count={colours.length / 4}
                  itemSize={4}
                  array={colours}
                  normalized={true}
                />
                <bufferAttribute
                  attachObject={["attributes", "uv"]}
                  count={uvs.length / 2}
                  itemSize={2}
                  array={uvs}
                  normalized={true}
                />
              </bufferGeometry>
              <meshPhongMaterial attach="material" color={0x88FF88} />
            </mesh>
        </Canvas>
      )
  };

  export default App;
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:
The issue here was with the react code. As buffer attributes requires all the arrays to be  `new Float32Array([...somepoints])`. After changing positions, uvs, normal and colours to float32 array type everything worked fine.